# Why am I getting invalid hook errors here in my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet

Trying to bring in Leaflet to display a map using code from their website. Saw a tutorial with a guy bringing in the same code with no errors - it's React typescript template btw
My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
<MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
  <TileLayer
    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  />
  <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
    <Popup>
        A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
    </Popup>
  </Marker>
</MapContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error:
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

---I've tried all three of those options, my React versions are the same (18.2), I only have one copy of React, but I'm not sure of the Rules of Hooks

Comment: Is there any sort of code stacktrace accompanying this error that might inform you exactly where the issue is?

Comment: Drew, thank you for your comment - I was able to get rid of the errors by re-installing the leaflet packages